# Django: Two relationships between two models

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm struggling with the creation of two models which have two relationships.

My goal is that a person can own multiple objects, and always has a favorite object (which they own).

So to be precise the constrains could be summed up like this:

- 1:n relationship Person - Object (a person [exclusively] owns multiple objects)
- n:1 relationship Person - Object (favorite object, every person has ONE favorite object)
- person.(favorite object).owner = person (a person must own their favorite object, that makes the n:1 relationship of the favorite object more like an "optional 1:1 from the object's perspective")

```py
class Person(models.Model):
    favorite_object = models.ForeignKey('Object')


class Object(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Person)
```

First of all, I get an error stating that I should add a `related_name` to help solve the reverse reference and I wonder what is the best thing to do here since the favorite relationship is optional from an object's perspective.

Do I alter owner to be

```py
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name="+")
```

to avoid the reverse reference in the first place?
But then, how can I query all objects of an owner?
And can I even enforce the constraint that the favorite object must be owned with the Django models?

---

Secondly, how do I create objects in the first place? They depend on each other.

I cannot create a user without having a favorite object and I cannot create an object without knowing its owner. Note that this is a necessary constraint in my case.

I would do something like this but it does not seem to work

```py
with transaction.atomic():
    my_person = Person()
    my_object = Object(owner=my_person)
    my_person.favorite_object = my_object
    my_person.save()
    my_object.save()
```

I could e.g., allow `Object.owner` to be NULL, but that would loosen my general constraint that every object needs to have an owner.

**Edit:**

It seems

```py
    favorite_object = models.ForeignKey('Object', related_name="+")
```

instead of excluding the reverse relationship might be a good idea because referencing back from the object to the owner seems unnecessary.
First of all, I can check the owner by the owner attribute anyway (my constraint is that the person who favours an object is also their owner).
And secondly that reverse relationship does not always exist.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could have a 'dummy' object in the database just so the Person() object has a favorite_object and does not fail to get created, then in the same view you create the person, use that person to create an object (which will be that persons favorite object) and update the Person() to have the object you just created instead of the dummy object.

i think it would look something like this:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes((AllowAny,))
def api_user_registration_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        dummy_object = Object.objects.get(name='dummy')
        person_serializer = PersonRegistrationSerializer(favorite_object=dummy_object, data=request.data)
        data = {

        }
        if person_serializer.is_valid():
            person = person_serializer.save()
            object_serializer = ObjectRegistrationSerializer(owner=person)
            if object_serializer.is_valid():
                object_serializer.save()
            else:
                data = serializer.errors
        else:
            data = serializer.errors
        return Response(data)
```

and in serializers.py you just declare the registration serializers for each model

```
class PersonRegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = '__all__'

class ObjectRegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Object
        fields = '__all__'
```

I hope this helps or at least point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so you would prefer a dummy object over setting `null=True`?
Also keep in mind that the dummy object can't exist without an owner either, which means you would also have to have a dummy owner. Which needs a dummy object to be create din the first place. You get the idea, it's a cyclic dependency